# When I use extends in django, my css files not working anymore

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

So first i write my code without extends and i am trying to use the extends feature now, normally my codes working without any problem but when i use `{% extends 'base.html' %}` css files stopped working.

**home.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %} 
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/home.css'%}">

    <link href="{% static 'fontawesomefree/css/solid.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="{% static 'fontawesomefree/js/all.min.js' %}"></script>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/swiper.min.css' %}">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/swiper.min.js' %}"></script>

    <title>kannom biraki enihime aratame</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}

    <div class="swiper mySwiper">
        <div class="category-header">
            <h1>bracelets</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            {% for bracelet in bracelet_list %}
            <div class="swiper-slide">

                <div class="slider-box">
                    <p class="time">New</p>
                    <div class="slider-image-box">
                        <img src="{{bracelet.image}}" alt="{{bracelet.title}}">
                    </div>
                    <p class="slider-detail">{{bracelet.title}}</p>
                    <p class="slider-price">{{bracelet.price}}</p>

                    <div class="slider-cart">
                        <a data-product="{{bracelet.id}}" class="add-to-cart" data-action="add"> Add to Cart </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <!-- <div class="swiper-slide">

                <div class="slider-box">
                    <p class="time">New</p>
                    <div class="slider-image-box">
                        <img src="{% static 'images/sponge-bob.jpg' %}" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <p class="slider-detail">Black ladies bags collections</p>
                    <p class="slider-price">30$</p>

                    <div class="slider-cart">
                        <a href="#">Add to cart</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="swiper-slide">

                <div class="slider-box">
                    <p class="time">New</p>
                    <div class="slider-image-box">
                        <img src="{% static 'images/sponge-bob.jpg' %}" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <p class="slider-detail">Black ladies bags collections</p>
                    <p class="slider-price">30$</p>

                    <div class="slider-cart">
                        <a href="#">Add to cart</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="category-header">
        <h1>all products</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="page-container">
        <div class="container">
            {% for product in product_list %}
            <div class="card">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="{{ product.image }}" alt="{{product.title}}" width="90%">
                    <ul class="action">
                        <li>
                            <a class="add-to-cart" data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="add"></button>
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
                                <span>Add to Cart</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i>
                            <span>Add to Wishlist</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i>
                            <span>Get Info</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- <a data-action="add" data-product="{{product.id}}"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></a> -->
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="product-name">
                        <h3>{{ product.title }}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-price">
                        <h3>{{product.price}}$</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}

        </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}

    <footer>
        <div class="footer-content">
            <h3>lira kuyumculuk</h3>
            <p>Lira kuyumclugu tercih ettiginiz icin tesekkur ederiz! Daha fazla bilgi icin bizleri sosyal medya
                uzerinden takip edebilir, guncel bir sekilde yeni gelen urunlerimizi takip edebilirsiniz.</p>
            <ul class="footer-socials">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-rights">
            <p>Tum haklar Lira Kuyumculuk A.S tarafindan saklanmistir</p>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script>
        var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetween: 30,
            pagination: {
                el: ".swiper-pagination",
                clickable: true,
            },
        });
    </script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/cart.js'%}"></script>
    <script>
                    var user = '{{request.user}}'
                    console.log(user)

                function getCookie(user) {
            let cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, user.length + 1) === (user + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(user.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
        const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    </script>
</body>
```

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="with=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>yokoso, watashi wa soul soceity!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" />
</head>

<body>
    <!-- {% include 'navbar.html' %} -->
    {%block content%}
    {%endblock%}
</body>
</html>
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Why do you have two `{% load static %}`? Also, please read this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/language/).

Comment: If you extend a template, don't repeat the base HTML structure (html, head, boy). Only put in your `{% block contents %}`.

Comment: @Coderio Because first i created templates of pages with js and css and it occurs me some problems about extend codes. Then i created all pages and functions now extend is the last problem. This is why i used load statics too much, this site is working all thing page by page.

Comment: @MichaelAnckaert Like i said its working page by page, its like kind of alfa stage, even that i changed whole project to make it more light. But i will delete all other html tags and see if its work.

Answer (score -1):

So i tried to import all the css and js files to base.html's header section, it gave me some css files but it looks like, my css files are in some conflict. So lesson one learned that its hard to combine your codes if you split it too much.